# Android Studio 1.5 - Gradle sync error gradle.properties file

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just updated Android Studio and I can't sync my project anymore.

[image: The event log reports:]

Comment: did you try switching it Off and On again? :)

Comment: yes... i already tried but still now i can't.

Comment: i mean restart your pc?

Comment: also, have you tried increasing the heap size as instructed in the error message?

Comment: Thank you waqaslam.... I relieve from my problem  Thanks again for your suggestion...

Comment: Please add an answer to explain what you did to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Android Studio Folder Where it is installed. There is File stduio.exe.vmoptions and studio64.exe.vmoptions, open it in notepad.

According to error you may need to change 2 values in it -

> -Xms512m 
>   -Xmx1280m

It should work. If it still does not work out try increasing the size.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Android Studio Folder Where it is installed. There is File `stduio.exe` and `studio64.exe` with file type of `VMOPTIONS`, open it in notepad you will see this:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.3
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

**According to error you may need to change two values in it.**

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1280m
```

check this value and change it.

Answer (score 0):

3 Way to solves :

1.Close all your browsers and other tools and then syn gradle again.

2.Go to **file > close project** and then go to **configure>settings>compiler** 
   In compiler set **1024** in **Build process heap size (Mbytes) :**

3.Open **gradle.property** file in Gradle Scripts drop down list and copy past this line :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```